# Where do the new super saiyan transformations fit in the power scale?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

In the last 4 years several new super saiyan transformations were introduced

- super saiyan god (assuming it counts as one)
- super saiyan god super saiyan or super saiyan blue
- super saiyan rage (trunks's new transformation)
- super saiyan rose
- and the recently canonized in a trailer preview, the legendary super saiyan (assuming the transformation has the same characteristics than Broly's one since it looks the same, bulky, yellowish green aura and blank eyes)

is it known where any of these transformations fit in the known power scale? (letting out all the half way transformations, ie, false super saiyan , ultra super saiyan , etc. for simplicity)

Base < Super Saiyan < Super Saiyan 2 < Super Saiyan 3

Where do the new transformations fit in this power scale showed above?

Comment: in manga 20: Rose is Black's version of the super saiyan blue

Answer (score 3):

Manga 22 (plus Manga 20 mentioned by Wouter in a commentary) stated several things. Now we know Super Saiyan Blue and Super Saiyan Rose are equivalent states, and that Super Saiyan God is inferior to Rose (and Blue). So only a couple of transformations are left to know where they fit, Super Saiyan Rage and the legendary-like Super Saiyan. To summarize,

Base < Super Saiyan < Super Saiyan 2 < Super Saiyan 3 < Super Saiyan God < Super Saiyan Blue = Super Saiyan Rose

Updated 03/06/2017. We don't have the multiplier for the Broly-like Super Saiyan green transformation, but we have an approximation. In Dragon Ball Super episode 93 (spoilers behind)

> Caulifla in SSJ2 is able to hold her own against Kale Broly-like Super Saiyan green transformation. Kyabe is surpassed in SSJ1.